# Cucumber CDI injection does not work with beans in src/main/java

Tags: java, cucumber, cdi, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I have a JEE application in a maven project using JUnit and Cucumber to test my code. The application is using CDI with weld-se in test scope.

I have created a simple feature file `src/test/resources/specification/first.feature`

```
Scenario: Identified user
  Given I am user A
```

Then I created the corresponding cucumber step:

```
public class FirstSteps {

@Inject
UserService userService;

@Given("^I am user A$")
public void i_am_user_A() throws Throwable {
    User user = User.new().withName("user A").create();
    assertThat(userService.getActualUser()).isEqualTo(user);
}

}
```

User Service is an Interface with one trivial implementation:

```
public interface UserService {
    User getActualUser();
}

public class FakeUserService implements UserService {

    @Override
    public User getActualUser() {
        return User.new().withName("user A").create();
    }

}
```

There are empty beans.xml files in `src/main/resources/META-INF` and `src/test/resources/META-INF`.

The step is located in `src/test/resources`, the service interface and its implementation in `src/main/java`.

And here is the JUnit-Test for it:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"classpath:specifikation"},
    glue = {"mypackage"})
public final class CucumberTests {
}
```

The step is found by cucumber and gets executed. But CDI does not work:

`Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type UserService with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject mypackage.FirstSteps.userService`

I have found [this issue on github for cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/915). But the solution does not work for me. I already have two empty beans.xml files in `src/main/resources/META-INF` and `src/test/resources/META-INF`.

It seems like the weld container creates a context for `src/test` only and everything in `src/main` does not belong to it. When I move the service interface and implementation to `src/test/java` it works...

Is there a way to reference beans in `src/main` from `src/test`?

EDIT: corrected location of the service interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your step is located in `src/test/java` and your service (interface) is located in `src/main/java` and not in `src/(test|main)/resources` (typo?), your setup should work.

Maybe check the following:

1. Ensure that your `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` folders are on the same classpath.
2. Assuming that you are using a current version of Weld which is CDI >1.1 compliant, ensure that both folders are [explicit bean archives](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/ee.html#_explicit_bean_archive).
3. Ensure your beans.xml files are literally empty or have [bean-discovery-mode set to all](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/when_your_di_breaks_bean).

If that does not work either, try to annotate your `FakeUserService`.

Comment: Thanks. It was the bean discovery: One beans.xml was laying in META-INF, but the other one in META_INF. Small typo with bad things to happen... ;)